# Как учитывать регистр при работе с sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Есть таблица улиц, ищу в ней, например, улицу Ленина...

Пишу так:

```
select name from streets where name like 'Лен%'
```

Ищет. Пишу так:

```
select name from streets where name like 'лен%'
```

Не ищет.

Оказалась проблема с регистром. В MySQL проблем с этим нет (адаптирую запросы с него). Что нужно сделать, чтобы SQLite не обращал внимание на регистр букв, также как и MySQL?

Comment: REGEXP '[Лл][Ее][Нн].+'

Comment: @wwvv эталонный ад

Comment: @sitev_ru, [говорят](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480319/case-sensitive-and-insensitive-like-in-sqlite), что ignorecase-поведение включается командой `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=OFF;` или добавлением [COLLATE NOCASE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing/973777#973777)

Comment: ничего не помогает... 
запрос "select * from streets where name like 'лен%';" выводит все строчки, где name написаны русскими буквами.. если английскими, то не выводит...

Comment: @sitev_ru, прошу прощения, это, видимо, только для ascii. Про utf8 говорят, что [присутствует беда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5582015) и надо переопределять фнукцию like.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from streets where ucase(name) like 'ЛЕН%'
```

Comment: наверное имелось в виду это:
select name from streets where upper(name) like 'ЛЕН%'

но тоже не работает корректно

Comment: И не забыть привести `лен` к верхнему регистру перед подстановкой в запрос. Костыль конечно, но по идее должно работать.

Comment: UPPER и LOWER в SQLite работает только с ASCII

Answer (score 1):

Чувствительность `LIKE` к регистру в SQLite управляется переменной `case_sensitive_like`. Соответственно

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;  # FOO != foo
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=OFF; # FOO == foo
```

**НО!** На сколько я понял нечувствительность к реестру (case insensivity) в sqlite из коробки работает только для латиницы. Объясняется это, на сколько я понял, тем что реализация нечувствительности к регистру для всего юникода потребовала-бы забивать sqlite очень много данный (вида ф=Ф, ы=Ы), а sqlite он всё-таки lite. Но есть какая-то возможность впилить в него поддержку case insensivity для кириллицы. Честно признаюсь что все мои знания по этому вопросу получены из беглого проглядывания [этой статьи на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150543/), к ней вас и отсылаю.

P.S. LIKE не лучший инструмент для полнотекстового поиска. Если поиск улицы это какая-то единичная задача то можно конечно обойтись этим, но всё-же полезно знать про специализированные инструменты полнотекстового поиска такие как Sphinx или Apache Lucene.